# Android, Redefine the search button

Tags: android, search, button

After several fruitless searches, I ask this question :

How can you redefine the "search" button an android phone?

I wish he would serve me something other than display a search box and a keyboard ...

Thank you

Regards

Vince

Answer (score 1):

I think this should answer your questions http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: hmmmmm, thanks i will think about it, i will keep you updated !

in fact, i want to desactivate the search box and the keyborard to do others things with the "search button" (like redirection to my first activity [this is an example])